# iOS5 stable app crashes in iOS 6 with dealloc:objc_storeStrong:objc_release:_dispatch_xref_dispose

Tags: objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, ios6

[NOTE: this Q&A is primary for a sliver of developers using blocks and queues who get a crash that is unexplainable.]

My app uses a dispatchQueue and when it gets dealloced I get this bizarre crash:

```
[MyClass dealloc]
objc_storeStrong
objc_release
_dispatch_xref_dispose
```

My app worked fine in iOS4.3 and iOS5.1, what the f happened????

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the the queue was suspended with a block queued in it. I have a flag that I set when I suspend the queue, dispatchQueueResumed, have a __block BOOL variable that says if the block should consider itself cancelled, and so I changed my dealloc as follows:

```
- (void)dealloc (
    if(!dispatchQueueResumed) {
        dispatchQueueCancel = YES;
        dispatch_resume(dispatchQueue);
        dispatch_group_wait(dispatchQueueGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
}
```